# GetAwaiter not using system

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, reference

I have example code and code I am currently writing.  Both set have the exact same references.  The example code HeartRateLE which I got from GitHub compiles and runs fine.  The code I am working on does not compile because of

this code

```
IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>  myTask =
              BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);
var device = myTask.GetAwaiter().GetResults();
```

as GetAwaiter does not reference using System;  Actually using System; at the top of the class is grayed out showing its not in use.

Both have the Reference of System and both have the same path of
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.8\System.dll

Both also have the Reference of Windows.WinMD  with the same path of
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD

Here is the error for GetAwaiter

> Error  CS4036  `'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>'` does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type `'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothLEDevice>'` could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)

I would like to know how to fix it so that GetAwaiter references System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below using, this is from the System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime assembly and holds a class with the GetAwaiter extensions.

using System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions;

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.

Answer (score 0):

using System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions;

For more info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.